# window.open does not work when print button is clicked for the second time in Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery

I m trying to print a particular div which works in both IE and Google Chrome. This is the code I have written.

```
function PrintElem(elem) {
        Popup($(elem).html());
    }
function Popup(data) {

        var mywindow = window.open('', 'Product Purchase Summary Page ','height=400,width=600');
        mywindow.document.write('<html><head><title>my div</title>');


        mywindow.document.write('</head><body onload="javascript:window.print();">');
        mywindow.document.write(data);
        mywindow.document.write('</body></html>');
        mywindow.print();


        if (navigator.userAgent.match(/MSIE/) !== null) {
            mywindow.location.reload();
        }          
        return true;
    }
```

The code works fine in IE. In chrome, on clicking the print button for the first time, it opens a print window. After the print window is closed, if I click on print button for the second time, window.open does not open a print window. It works only for the first time. Print button does nothing from the second time.
 But when I click on cancel button (instead of closing) in the print window, second time button click works just fine.
Can anyone help?

Comment: where are you calling `PrintElem` from? you may want to include your html...

Comment: @webeno  <input type="button" onclick="PrintElem('#print')" value="Print" class="btn btn-success button" />

Comment: It works fine with me on Chrome v 33.0.1750.117

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, I have been facing exactly the same problem with Chrome 34. I updated this morning to Chrome 36 and the problem is fixed.

In any case, you may want to try this, it fixed the problem for me by putting the focus-pring-close functionalities inside the pop-up.

```
<HTML>
  <HEAD><TITLE>PRINT TEST</TITLE></HEAD>
  <BODY>
    <button label="print" onclick="print();">print</button>
  </BODY>

  <script>
  function print() {
    var datawindow = window.open("", "data", "height=400,width=600");
    datawindow.document.write("<html><head><title>data</title>");
    datawindow.document.write("</head><body onload='window.focus();window.print();' onbeforeunload='window.close();' ><pre><code>");
    datawindow.document.write("SOMETHING TO PRINT GOES HERE");
    datawindow.document.write("</code></pre></body></html>");
    datawindow.document.close();
    datawindow.close();
    this.__handlePrintSuccess();
  }
  </script>
</HTML>
```

Note the `onload='window.focus();window.print();'` and `onbeforeunload='window.close();'`

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).on("click", "#printBtn", function()
{

    // Code [ Tap.. Tap.. Tap..]

});
```

Comment: Try to be more descriptive in your explanation.
 In addition to adding the code as response, try to add a brief explanation of why comes in handy.